# Navigation bar and links flicker/jump/resize when navigating between pages, how to fix?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

My navigation bar and its links tend to exhibit some odd behavior when navigating between pages. When clicking a link, the navigation items jump, flicker, or the links rearrange briefly before "settling" into their proper places. This happens most times, and is worst on the My Blog page. I'm thinking this may be an issue with my CSS, but I'm not entirely sure what the cause is. How can I remedy the situation?

My site is: www.tylercharboneauprofessional.com

Here's my code:

```
#navigation-top {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #358fd4;
  opacity: .97;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  }

.horizontal-navigation-bar nav ul li a { 
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0 .95em;
   }

body .active-link>a, .text .active-link>a:visited {
  border-bottom: .5px solid #000;
  margin: 0 11px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  }

.horizontal-navigation-bar nav ul li a:after {
   background: transparent;
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: 1px;
   margin-bottom: -1px;
   transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
   width: 0;
   }

.horizontal-navigation-bar nav ul li a:hover:after {
   background: #000;
   width: 100%;
   }

#site-title {
  padding: 0;
  }
```

Comment: You need to reproduce the problem with code in your post. Not just include a little bit of CSS and a link to your site.

Comment: @Michael Coker I suppose I could, if I knew which portion exactly was causing the problem. Unfortunately screenshots will not work in capturing the issues, and I can't easily access my HTML since I'm using a supplied template

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;` is causing that. Did you try to comment part of your css to see if some of it causing the problem?

Comment: Hey @Oleg Markoff - Just out of curiosity, what made you suspect that was the culprit? I tried removing the effect, and it did seem to provide some slight improvements. I assume this is because it's one of the more "expensive" CSS effects in regards to my navigation. However, the Blog page is still as awful as ever, and while improved the other pages are still not perfect. Something odd seems to be tripping that certain page

Comment: Unfortunately the css only does not give more hints. I see that your images are "jumping", it looks like that they are dynamically adjusted to particular size, but it is only the guess.